# Lower bound $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n/(a_n -1)$ in terms of $a_1$, where $a_n$ is an infinite sequence under some conditions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

This is a question related to a previous question ([$a_n$ is an infinite sequence with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\leq1$ and $0\leq a_n<1$. Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n/(a_n-1)$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131469/a-n-is-an-infinite-sequence-with-sum-limits-n-1-infty-a-n-leq1-and-0-le)).

This time, I want to give a lower bound on the following infinite sum. $a_n$ is an infinite sequence with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\leq1$ and $0\leq a_n<1$. W.l.o.g., we sort the $a_n$ in descending order, and set $a_1$ equal to $0 < c < 1$. Is it possible to give a lower bound on the sum in terms of $c$ on $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{a_n-1}$?

I tried Taylor series, writing the sum in different forms; Jensen's inequaly is the wrong way around...

Comment: try using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: $-\frac{1}{1-c}$ will do since $1-a_n \geq 1-c$ and the original sum is positive but $\leq 1$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise that it was that simple!