# Proof writing: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}| a_n|<\infty $ implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2<\infty $.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ be an absolutely converging series.  By definition, this means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_n\rvert $ converges. We want to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^2_n $ converges absolutely as well.

---

Here is what I tried:

Let's say $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_n^2\rvert $ converges. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and there exists $N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that

$\lvert a^2_{m+1}\rvert+ \lvert a^2_{m+2}\rvert + \dots+ \lvert a^2_{n}\rvert< \epsilon$ for all $ n > m \geq N $. By the triangle inequality,

$$\lvert a^2_{m+1} + a^2_{m+2} + \dots + a^2_{n}\rvert \leq \lvert a^2_{m+1}\rvert+ \lvert a^2_{m+2}\rvert + \dots + \lvert a^2_{n}\rvert $$

so the Cauchy Criterion guarantees that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^2_n $ also converges.

---

Here is my **question**:

> Is this correct, or do I need to prove anything else?

Comment: "Let's say $\sum |a_n^2|$ converges" this is what you want to prove, you can't start with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ is convergent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36429/if-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-is-absolutely-convergent-then-sum-n-1-infty)

Comment: @Clement: No, it’s not a duplicate, because it asks specifically whether the argument given is correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My bad. Clicked before actually thinking. (I retracted the closing vote.)

Comment: Apparently someone would prefer that the OP’s confusion not be remedied, since the question and all three answers have been downvoted.

Comment: Yes, downvoting seems to be a very contagious disease these days...

Comment: I've edited the question, could someone take a look at it now?

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to why $|a^2_n| \leq |a_n|$. It seems intuitive to me that it would be the opposite. Could someone explain this part?

Comment: (1): the last inequality (the first) is wrong, it should be $0 \leq a_n^2 < \lvert a_n\rvert$ (for $n\geq N$). (the reason is: when $x\in[0,1]$, we have $0\leq x^2 = x\cdot x \leq 1\cdot x = x$). (2) I am not entirely sure about the policy, but completely changing your question after it got several answers seems slightly off to me. Instead, you could for instance have *added* the new content *after* the previous one, prefixing it with an "Edit" notice?

Comment: Sorry, I will next time.

Comment: Regarding $|a_n^2| \leq |a_n|$.  There are two kinds of $|a_n|$:  those that are less then $1$ and the others.  How can you show there are only finitely many of "the others"?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not correct: you’ve proved that if $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n^2$ converges absolutely, then it converges, which is not at all what you’re supposed to be doing. You have assumed precisely the result that you are supposed to be proving, and you’ve ignored the hypothesis.

You should be assuming that $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n$ converges absolutely and using *that* assumption to prove that $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n^2$ converges absolutely.

HINT: If $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n$ converges absolutely, then there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_n|<1$ for each $n\ge m$ (why?), and hence $0\le|a_n^2|<|a_n|$ for each $n\ge m$.

Comment: Actually addressing the question... (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Since $(a_n)$ converges absolutely, $\lim_n\mid a_n\mid=0$. This implies there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $\mid a_n\mid <1$. This implies that for $n>N$, $\mid a^2_n\mid<\mid a_n\mid$.

Comment: The hint is valid, but the question is "*Is this correct,* or do I need to prove anything else?" not "give me a way to do it."   (emphasis mine)

Comment: hello can you explain how did you get $|a_n|<1$? did you use the geometric criterion? thnk you.

Comment: @Elina Take $\epsilon=1/2$. Since $|a_n| \to 0$, there exists an $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that beyond this $m$ all $a_n$ lie in the $\epsilon=1/2$ interval of $0$ and hence $||a_n|-0|<1/2\rightarrow|a_n|<1$

Answer (score 0):

Brian has already pointed out what is wrong with your reasoning. Here is another approach.

Note that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|<\infty$, then 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^2_n}{|a_n|} = \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| = 0.$$

Then take a look at [the limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

---

[Might not be useful for now though]
In real analysis,  this is nothing but a simple case of a more general theorem (see for instance Folland's Real Analysis, Chapter 6)
$$
\ell^p(\mathbb{N})\subset\ell^q(\mathbb{N})
$$
for $0<p<q\leq\infty$.